# Is there some episode list for Game of Thrones that rates how violent each episode is?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Some episodes are milder than others and it would be nice to know how much to brace myself for each week. I really like the plot and everything is interesting (ie don't want to stop watching the show), but it's upsetting sometimes how there is a lot of sexual violence in certain episodes and as a survivor of sexual violence I want to prepare myself mentally before watching those.

Comment: I could not agree more. Some episodes are just plain disturbing, and the scenes too long and too explicit. Where the book hints about cruelty and torture, the TV-show spends whole episodes about it.

Comment: I don’t know of a single source, but a search for “Game of Thrones trigger warnings” turns up some stuff for individual episodes. (And if there isn’t a single source for this stuff, then somebody should probably make one.)

Comment: Fair warning, you are unlikely to find a site that details how much and what kind of violence is contained in each episode without also significantly spoiling important events in the episode.  If you've read the books this isn't as big a deal, but still an issue.

Comment: The warning at each episode's start does address the concern you have. The difference with the GOT shows is that a visual aspect presents implied or hinted situations in the books. Violence in a violent society as presented on HBO has no punches pulled or sugar coating applied. It's not likely to get milder, just the opposite.

Answer (score 22):

The IMDb page for *Game of Thrones* has a [Parents Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/parentalguide), which has sections for “Violence/Gore” and “Frightening/Intense Scenes”.

This guide includes episode references, and fairly specific descriptions of any scenes which include sexual assault or similar. Major spoilers are hidden by default, unless you hover your mouse over them (similar to this site).

This page seems fairly up-to-date: the latest edit was 13 hours ago (as I write my answer), and includes details of an episode aired last Sunday. I looked around for other similar resources, and most of them hadn’t been maintained.

Individual episode pages also have a “content advisory” for Parents, with a link just below the cast listing. However, not every episode has this page.

**Disclaimer:** I don’t watch GoT, so I can’t testify to its accuracy or completeness.

**ETA:** I should also point out that the IMDb editors don’t get to see *GoT* in advance, so this is only of help if you’re willing to wait for this page to be edited before you watch the latest episodes.

Comment: I've had a look at the "violence" section of that IMDB guide. It's pretty thorough, but a few problems: No season 6, spoilers in seasons 1 and 2 not marked (the description of S1E9/S1E10 is especially spoilery, ignore it and go with "a man is killed, then next episode part of the corpse is shown graphically"). Several scenes of attempted or actual sexual violence are missing: off the top of my head, S3E3 (male victim, violent but narrow escape), S4E5 (female prisoner threatened, narrow escape), S5E6 (female, very distressing and emotionally intense, not violent, audible off screen)

Comment: Oh and I forgot S4E3, a major one, a very disturbing, quite graphic, quite violent scene between two major characters too weird to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 9):

The [Guardian website](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/series/game-of-thrones-episode-by-episode) is running an episode by episode guide.

Each recap contains a considerable level of detail regarding the violence and sexual content in each episode. Unfortunately it's incredibly spoilerish so I'd suggest you read the books first (where the emotional content will be far easier to cope with) , then use the guide to help you with the TV show.

Comment: I checked up randomly some articles on that page. You can scroll down to "violence count" (apparently there is this section in every article) and see what to expect. It still is somewhat spoilerish, but most of the time it's hard to figure out the events of that episode by just reading that section.

Comment: This is good - but a little understated for my purposes. "a glimpse into the daily horrors of life in Craster's Keep" doesn't really help me prepare for the scene how he orders the men to 'f* them until they're dead'. (for the latest episode "Oathkeeper")

Comment: Regarding reading the books first: In the specific case of _Game of Thrones_, the show is much more sexually explicit and even includes many scenes that weren’t in the books at all.

Comment: @bdesham - Which is why I'd recommend reading the books (e.g. to render the possibility of spoilers moot) before reading the warnings and guides which are spoileriffic

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I didn’t read your answer carefully enough :-) You’re right; that strategy is a good one.